# Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'?

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication

I'm getting an error: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpUserEvent, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { LoginService } from "../services/login.service";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> { // here error

        if (req.headers.get('No-Auth') == "True")
            return next.handle(req.clone());

        if (localStorage.getItem('userToken') != null) {
            const clonedreq = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('userToken'))
            });
            return next.handle(clonedreq)
                .do(
                succ => { },
                err => {
                    if (err.status === 401)
                        this.router.navigateByUrl('/signin');
                }
                );
        }
        else {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/sigin');
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried do it with try but I'm still getting the same error.

> Does anyone knows how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method you provided `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`as a return type. Therefore you need to return this type object from this method.

According to your method you only return object in if condition. You just want to return this kind object with else part as well.

```
   else {
            return next.handle(req.clone())
            .do(
            succ => { this.router.navigateByUrl('/sigin') },
            );
        }
```

*Below things are general things that you can do with this kind of error. But **you cannot use below mechanisms here**. Because you are implementing HttpInterceptor here..*

This is kind of option here. If u really want to this not to return any thing in else part, u just need to change your method signature as below

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> | undefined
```

or u can just remove the return part from signature

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler)
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error: Property 'intercept' in type 'AuthInterceptor' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'HttpInterceptor'.
  Type '(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) => Observable<HttpEvent<any>> | undefined' is not assignable to type '(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) => Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'.
    Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'.

Comment: I edited my answer there.@Nikola . can you try out that

Comment: any
Cannot find name 'clonedreq'.ts

Comment: If I do clonedreq:any I've got: any
Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)
'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: here you can try out req.clone() instead of clonedReq. Use whatever variable that suitable for that else condition. It just need Observable<HttpEvent<any>> type

Comment: Can you please accept the answer If it works :) and happy to help u. Happy coding @Nikola